# In .NET, find the start and end indices of a section of an array read in from an OBJ file

Tags: .net, vb.net, indexof

I have an OBJ file that I read into an array of objects.  I then use Array.IndexOf to, first, find the object layer section I want to deal with, and then, obtain the start and end index of the lines that start with "vt" in that section.  I can get the proper index of the object layer, but the other two indices show up as -1.

Here's a truncated version of the OBJ with one object.

```
o Layer_1_Hull
.
.
.
o Layer_2_Mainsail                         '=== Finds index of specified object layer first,
v 13.747500 283.669006 411.285187          '=== Layer_2_Mainsail object layer in this case
v 13.747500 283.669006 411.275177
v 13.797300 283.483002 411.275177
vt 0.900824 0.386317                       '=== Finds index of the first instance of "vt"
vt 0.900895 0.386336
vt 0.871146 0.496693
vt 0.871075 0.496673                       '=== Finds index of the last instance of "vt"
vn -0.9660 -0.2587 0.0000
vn -0.9660 0.2587 0.0000
vn -0.7071 0.7072 0.0000
vn -0.2592 0.9658 0.0000
```

The code I use

```
    Option Explicit On
    .
    .
    .
    Dim objArray As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Dude\Project\Sailboat.obj")
    Dim layerIndex As Integer = Array.IndexOf(objArray, "o " + "Layer_2_Mainsail")
    Dim uvStartIndex As Integer = Array.IndexOf(objArray, "vt ", layerIndex)       '=== Returns -1, why??
    Dim uvEndIndex As Integer = Array.IndexOf(objArray, "vn ", uvStartIndex) - 1   '=== index out of bounds
```

Appreciate the help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Why `objArray As Object()`? It should be `… As String()`. Relatedly, be sure to use `Option Explicit On`. **Always.**

Comment: The result is still the same, though, Konrad.  -1 for uvStartIndex

Comment: `Array.IndexOf()` searches for the whole content of the string. Partial strings won't match. Use `File.ReadLines()`, iterate the collection and increment an integer variable for each iteration. Use `String.StartsWith()` and store the first and last match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write it like this:

```
 Dim lines = File.ReadLines("C:\Users\Dude\Project\Sailboat.obj").
      SkipWhile(Function(line) Not line.StartsWith("o " + "Layer_2_Mainsail")).
      SkipWhile(Function(line) Not line.StartsWith("vt ")).
      TakeWhile(Function(line) Not line.StartsWith("vn "))
```

See it work here (the link will also show any `Imports` directives you may need to add):

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/767zkX

As for why the existing code failed, I suspect there is extra whitespace following the target text, so the line is not an exact match for the search key.

Comment: I used Array.IndexOf(objArray, Function(x) x.Contains("vt "), layerIndex)) which works, but then I saw this and like it better.  Thank you.